# long delay when calling cocoa method

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ipad

I have a method for saving the contents of a UIScrollView with a user-supplied filename.

Everything works fine, except that there is a long delay when the user taps the "Save" button and the method is called. I can't work out what's calling the delay, nor find a way to indicate to the user that everything is ok, we have not crashed!

I thought the delay was occurring during the renderInContext, but it seems to be happening a lot earlier, when there is not much else going on.

Here is the troublesome method:

```
- (void)captureViewImage {

    NSLog(@"captureViewImage called!");

// long delay happens here!

    fileNamer.title = @"Preparing to save...";

    // get user's file name
    NSString *fileName = fileNamer.fileNameField.text;

    // dismiss keyboard
    [fileNamer.fileNameField resignFirstResponder];

    // dismiss modal view
    [self dismissFileNamingFormSheet];

    CGRect oldFrame = mainScrollView.frame;

    // capture off-screen content
    mainScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1432);

    // make screenshot
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mainScrollView.bounds.size);
    [mainScrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // save screenshot in docs dir
    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenImg);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    [pngData writeToFile:[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] 
                 options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];

    // revert scroll view
    mainScrollView.frame = oldFrame;

}
```

fileNamer is a custom class that throws up a UIModalPresentationFormSheet asking the user to supply a name for the file. It looks like this:

```
@implementation FileNamingViewController

@synthesize fileNameField, newFileName;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil parent:(TestDriveViewController *) myParent {

    if (self == [super initWithNibName:@"FileNamingViewController" bundle:nil]) {
        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                        initWithTitle:@"Save" 
                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                        target:myParent 
                                        action:@selector(captureViewImage)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
        [rightButton release];

        UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                        initWithTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                        target:myParent 
                                        action:@selector(dismissFileNamingFormSheet)];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;
        [leftButton release];

        self.title = @"Save As?";
    }
    return self;
}


// UITextFieldDelegate

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [fileNameField resignFirstResponder];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [fileNameField becomeFirstResponder];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

fileNamer is initialized and released as follows:

```
- (void)presentFileNamingFormSheet {
    fileNamer = [[FileNamingViewController alloc] 
                 initWithNibName:nil 
                 bundle:nil 
                 parent:self];

    fileNamingNavCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                        initWithRootViewController:fileNamer];

    fileNamingNavCtrl.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    [self presentModalViewController:fileNamingNavCtrl
                            animated:YES];

    // resize modal form sheet
    fileNamingNavCtrl.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 540, 115);

    // reposition modal form sheet
    CGPoint position = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y - 50);
    fileNamingNavCtrl.view.superview.center = position;
}

- (void)dismissFileNamingFormSheet {
    [fileNamer release];
    [fileNamingNavCtrl release];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}
```

Output from Time Profiler:

```
Running (Self)      Symbol Name
1109.0ms   37.0%    argb32_image_mark_rgb32
328.0ms   10.9%     blkclr
171.0ms    5.7%     lo_alltraps
134.0ms    4.4%     pmap_enter
116.0ms    3.8%     png_write_find_filter
102.0ms    3.4%     pmap_remove_range
55.0ms    1.8%      pmap_get_mapwindow
47.0ms    1.5%      vm_page_lookup
47.0ms    1.5%      ml_set_interrupts_enabled
43.0ms    1.4%      vm_page_grab
38.0ms    1.2%      OSAddAtomic64
34.0ms    1.1%      hw_lock_to
31.0ms    1.0%      alphaProviderGetBytes
30.0ms    1.0%      hw_lock_unlock
26.0ms    0.8%      png_read_filter_row
25.0ms    0.8%      deflateInit_
23.0ms    0.7%      vm_map_lookup_entry
23.0ms    0.7%      adler32
22.0ms    0.7%      memory_object_recover_named
```

Comment: Where is fileNamer initialized?

Comment: You're in the best position to answer this question. Instruments is the proper tool for measuring what your application is spending its time doing. Particularly the Time Profiler instrument. Run your application in Instruments (using the Time Profiler) and *you* tell *us* what it's doing. Then we can diagnose why.

Comment: fileNamer is initialized in my main view controller, same place as the code above is taken from. I will edit the original post to show the initialization of fileNamer.

Comment: Logging messages between method calls should tell you which method is taking the most time. You can also get a higher level view of CPU usage by adjusting the filter rules in Instruments.

Comment: Since you're saying that it seems to be happening before renderInContext, the custom code you've not shown us before that point is `dismissFileNamingFormSheet`. What does it do?

Comment: dismissFileNamingFormSheet does what it says on the tin. It's up there if you want to take a look. The delay happens immediately after captureViewImage is called. fileNamer's title does not change until after a delay of several seconds. Yet it should take no time at all for that to happen. When I insert the NSLog call at the start of captureViewImage, that happens immediately when the method is called, but there's still a long delay before the title change happens. If I remove the title change, there is a long delay before the keyboard disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was causing this. The image I was saving contained a lot of transparent views. For example, I had a lot of UIButtons which had an alpha value of 0.05 to make them more or less disappear. I didn't realise I could just set the button type to custom to make it invisible (I created the view along time ago). Once I set everything in my image view to have an alpha value of 1.0, the saving process became a lot quicker.